# jQuery slider get stuck in a loop when a control is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I have a simple automatic jQuery slider that goes changes pictures every few seconds and i added a few divs that should jump to a certain slide when hovered

This is my code

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div id="options">
      <div class="option" onmouseover="show1();">
      </div>
      <div class="option" onmouseover="show2();">
      </div>
      <div class="option" onmouseover="show3();">
      </div>
      <div class="option" onmouseover="show4();">
      </div>
      <div class="option" onmouseover="show5();">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="pic" id="pic-1">
        <img src="img/1">
      </div>
      <div class="pic" id="pic-2">
        <img src="img/2">
      </div>
      <div class="pic" id="pic-3">
        <img src="img/3">
      </div>
      <div class="pic" id="pic-4">
        <img src="img/4">
      </div>
      <div class="pic" id="pic-5">
        <img src="img/5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pic').hide();
    i=1;
    function slider(){

    $('#pic-'+i).fadeIn('0').delay(1000).fadeOut('0',function(){
    i=i+1;if(i==6){i=1;}slider();

    });

    }
    slider();
    });
    function show1(){
        $('#pic-1').fadeIn('0').delay(1000).fadeOut('0')
    }
    function show2(){
        $('#pic-2').fadeIn('0').delay(1000).fadeOut('0')
    }
    function show3(){
        $('#pic-3').fadeIn('0').delay(1000).fadeOut('0')
    }
    function show4(){
        $('#pic-4').fadeIn('0').delay(1000).fadeOut('0')
        }
    function show5(){
        $('#pic-5').fadeIn('0').delay(1000).fadeOut('0')
    }
```

The problem with is that at first the slideshow works fine until i hover an element and the animation starts looping for a few times, is there an easy fix that doesn't require me re-writing it?

Answer (score 0):

I've reduced the number of images for testing it, you can add then as much images as you want.

I've modified your html adding some custom attributes data-pic to the divs. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/jth30720/1/

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
  <div id="options">
    <div class="option" data-pic="pic-1">1</div>
    <div class="option" data-pic="pic-2">2</div>
    <div class="option" data-pic="pic-3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="pic" id="pic-1">
    <img src="http://www.panic.com/blog/wp-content/themes/panic/images/icon_smile2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="pic" id="pic-2">
    <img src="http://www.panic.com/blog/wp-content/themes/panic/images/icon_sad2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="pic" id="pic-3">
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/logotypes/32/square-facebook-20.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

And for the script, I've modified practically everything. Then you can adapt the time of your fade animations as you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pic').hide();
  i=1;
  interv = setInterval(slider, 2000);
});
$(".option").hover(
  function() {
    clearInterval(interv);
    $('#'+$(this).attr("data-pic")).fadeIn('0');
  }, function() {
  $('#'+$(this).attr("data-pic")).fadeIn('0').fadeOut('10000',function(){
      interv = setInterval(slider, 2000);
  });
}
);
function slider(){
  $('#pic-'+i).fadeIn('0').fadeOut('10000',function(){
    i=i+1;
    if(i==4) i=1;
});
}
```

I hope that's what you wanted to achieve